# Is the derivative a scalar function, too?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a function $x(t)\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, then $x^2(t)$ is a scalar function.

Is then $\frac{dx^2(t)}{dt}$ a scalar function, too?

Intuitively, my answer is yes, since the derivative is a linear approximation of $x^2(t)$ and so it should be a sclar function, too.

Comment: By $x^2(t)$, do you mean the dot product of $x(t)$ with itself?

Comment: In any case, yes, the derivative of a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is itself $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, no matter how you came across the original function.

Comment: Yes, I mean sclar product.

Comment: Is this by definition that it is again $R\to R$?

Comment: x @Salamo: That's how you learned to take derivatives in high school, isn't it? The fact that your $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ function was _defined_ via some vector algebra doesn't change the fact that _once you get around to differentiate it_, it's just some $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ function, and you know (or ought to know) what the derivative of such a thing means.

Answer (score 0):

Note that what you are differentiating is the composite map 
$$
\varphi: t \mapsto x(t) =: y \mapsto \sum_{k}y_{k}^{2}: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R},
$$
where the first map $f$ maps $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ and the second $g$ maps $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ to $\Bbb{R}$; hence $Dg: \Bbb{R}^{n} \to \Bbb{R}$ and $Df: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^{n}$. But then by chain rule $D\varphi = Dg \cdot Df: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$.